# How do I fix DirectX error "0x887A0005 (0x887A0007) (6070) D" when launching Call of Duty: Modern Warfare II?

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-ii

[image: Error message screenshot]

> Call of Duty HQ - Crash handler
>
> DirectX Error
>
> DirectX encountered an unrecoverable error
>
> To contact customer service support, go to https://support.activision.com/modern-warfare-ii
> Error Code: 0x887A0005 (0x887A0007) (6070) D
> Signature: 424297AD-7923486E-E21BFC67-A52CFC22
> Location: 0x00007FF9D3E24B2C (15208310)
> Executable: game_ship.exe

I get this error for some reason every time I try to launch *Call of Duty: Modern Warfare II*.

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest graphics driver for your GPU?

Comment: Yep. I've even downloaded some apps to make sure i have the latest version of all drivers.